# TypeError: `Conv2D` can accept only 2 positional arguments ('filters', 'kernel_size'), but you passed the following positional arguments:

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, typeerror

I'm trying to run a CNN, but I get this message:

```
TypeError: `Conv2D` can accept only 2 positional arguments ('filters', 'kernel_size'), but you passed the following positional arguments: [64, (3, 3), (1, 1)]
```

My code is:

```
num_filters_conv1 = 64
kernel_size_conv1 = (3,3)
stride_conv1 = (1,1)
padding_conv1 = 'valid'
input_shape = (rows, cols, 1)

model.add(Conv2D(num_filters_conv1, kernel_size_conv1, stride_conv1, padding_conv1, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
```

Anyone knows what's going on? Why are the kernel and padding not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strides and padding are keyword arguments.
Reference: https://keras.io/backend/#conv2d
Try instead:

```
model.add(Conv2D(num_filters_conv1, kernel_size_conv1, 
                 strides=stride_conv1, padding=padding_conv1, 
                 activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
```